# Returning a Blank Message, need Exception for document.getElementById

Tags: html, vb.net, getelementbyid

I have a form that works with one exception, when a user doesn't fill out the text boxes and click submits it sends a blank email.  What I would like to do is if the user clicks submit and the form is blank, have a message popup (in a new window or same, doesn't matter) that requires them to fill out the form prior to submitting.  Overall, the goal is to not have a blank email sent.

The HTML button code is as follows:

```
<a href="#" class="SubBtn" onclick="document.getElementById('form').submit()">Submit</a>
<a href="#" class="ResBtn" onclick="document.getElementById('form').reset()">Reset</a>
```

I'm not sure if there needs to be exception handling in this situation, or if it a javascript would be a proper fix.  Or if there is a simple fix beyond that, please help.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To accomplish this all that is needed, is a javascript validation function.

Here is a link that will show how it is done for empty fields as well as email fields (where a valid email address me present to validate.)

http://www.w3schools.com/jS/js_form_validation.asp